# How can I mask URLs with subdirectories to display the same URL?

Tags: php, apache, url-rewriting, subdirectory, masking

We have a website called `example.com`

I want these paths and their subdirectories:

`example.com/vip/members/alice/watch`

`example.com/vip/members/alice/bag`

to be permanently displayed to visitors as:

`example.com/vip/alice`

In order for the `/watch`, `/bag`, and other subdirectories not to be displayed in the URL address bar. In other words, I want to hide the full URL of these subdirectories in the browser.

Comment: Just clarify, do you want visitors to be able to click on links either on your site or in search engines and have all directories below `example.com/vip/alice` to display the content for that page, but with `example.com/vip/alice` as the URL in the browser?

Comment: Yes. Exactly that

Comment: Unless you plan on using just links to find these pages, which is why I asked about search engines, this isn't a very good idea for SEO. Search engines will just see the same URL as what's in the browser. Explaining why you want to do this might be helpful to getting better answers.

Comment: I clarified the question for you, though it would be best if you add why you're trying to accomplish this since masking can be tricky and has caveats (such as duplicate content and indexing issues).

Comment: Just like when you google : alice silverstone (just an example name) google wont show you all her subdirs. Facebook will also display for example : facebook.com/alice.silverstone.54

Comment: I dont want complex indexation and seo about that don't worry. I just need the technique to perform it if you can help

Comment: You can't have one URL (eg. `/vip/alice`) refer to two different "subdirectories" (eg. `/vip/members/alice/watch` and `/vip/members/alice/watch`)? "Hiding" _subdirectories_ (or URL-path segments) requires changing the URL structure througout your application. URL-rewriting is just part of this process. Have you already changed the URLs in your application?

Comment: You all overcoplicated the question in your mind. Here is a working solution I grabbed somewhere, thanks anyway : http://imgur.com/a/TrPv0

Comment: @ChicsMamans That "image link" doesn't show anything? Please add your solution as an answer - we are curious to know what you actually meant and I'm sure it will help others. Thanks.

Comment: What you are asking is not possible or practical. As well, you are losing valuable semantic value in losing /bag or /watch. Semantic value is how search engines assess what the page is about. The path is one of the most powerful semantic clues you can give. I would recommend either leaving the path as is or just removing /members from the list. This is possible with a rewrite. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution with external help. This is what I was looking for with mod_proxy enabled in httpd configuration:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^$ /vip/alice [NC,P]
```